# attach to previously opened puppeteer driver

Tags: puppeteer

Is it possible to reattach to an existing puppeteer ?

1. open puppeteer chrome browser.
2. node script ends without closing browser.
3. new script attaches and continue with the same browser.

Comment: Have you seen `puppeteer.connect()`? https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#puppeteerconnectoptions

Comment: oh yes, I've solved the issue, forgot about this thread, thanks.
writing the session to a file then using .connect solved it.

Comment: Kindly accept answer if you think it is right.

Comment: OP mentions "writing the session to file" as a solution in the comments.   For helpful  example of saving/loading cookies between sessions, see https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1316#issuecomment-468581416

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For those who stumble upon this, here's an example of how I've got it working:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

puppeteer.connect({"browserWSEndpoint" : "ws://some_string"}).then(async browser => {
    console.log("bla bla");
    ...
});
```

The [browser.wsEndpoint](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#browserwsendpoint) you can find from the previous session:

```
const endpoint = browser.wsEndpoint();
```

Browser websocket endpoint which can be used as an argument to [puppeteer.connect](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#puppeteerconnectoptions).

Comment: OP mentions "writing the session to file" as a solution in the comments.   For helpful  example of saving/loading cookies between sessions, see https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1316#issuecomment-468581416