# How to remain Chromium opened using Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, chromium, puppeteer

I want to launch only one Chromium instance from first script and then attach to it from other scripts. I know about puppeteer.connect() but the problem is that I start the script which is supposed to launch Chromium:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');
const logger = fs.createWriteStream('log.txt', {
  flags: 'a' // 'a' means appending (old data will be preserved)
});

(async() => {
  const browser = await  puppeteer.launch({ headless: false});
  logger.write('-----Browser is launched\n');
  logger.write(browser.wsEndpoint());
})();
```

...and it never ends because I didn`t do browser.close(). Thus, I can`t start running other scripts. How can I launch Chromium, obtain its endpoint and end the script remaining Chromium launched.

([This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45867611/attach-to-previously-opened-puppeteer-driver) doesn`t contain an appropriate answer)

Comment: Why doesn't https://stackoverflow.com/a/46364111/274673 (`puppeteer.connect`) work for you?

Comment: "Thus, I can`t start running other scripts." -- I don't see any reason why not. What do these _other scripts_ look like?

Answer (score -2):

**Answering question**

- Basically you can spawn `child_process` with detached set to true. Then exit your main script with `process.exit()` to launch Chromium see **1.js**.
- Script that responsible to launch Chromium and saving the web socket see **chromiumLauncher.js**
- When the web socket are saved, you can connect via puppeteer.launch see **2.js**

[Here](https://github.com/brutalcrozt/puppeteer/tree/dev-enter/examples/connect) i push it on github (dirty code).